# Reading Data via Bluetooth from Choicemed Oximeter MD300C318T

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I´m trying to connect my Android app to a Choicemed Oximeter. I can´t find any information on how this should be done. My app also supports a Polar Wearlink Heart Rate Monitor which can be paired just fine. Any ideas or information?

Comment: i also need the communication protocol of the MD300C318T, can't find it anywhere. have you succeeded? I see you published a paper about it :P

Comment: Hi, yes I have received the protocol. http://www.pulsoximeter-gerate.com/ has a Online help desk chat. I wrote I needed id for a Bachelor Thesis and they emailed it right away!

Comment: Hi Hans, since you got the solution, please provide an answer to your question, it's already attracting NAAs.

Comment: Hi bummi, sorry I no longer have the required file, but I assume the link above still works and they will happily provide any necessary information.